# Hard link to a symbolic link with Win32 API?

Tags: c, winapi, filesystems, symlink, ntfs

Quick background to this question as I'm sure it'll raise a few eyebrows: I'm developing a command line tool in C for making backups, and I am implementing incremental backups using NTFS hard links. Thus, if symbolic links exists in a prior backup, I must be able to point to the symbolic links themselves, not the target.

Unfortunately, the page for [CreateHardLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createhardlinkw) clearly states:

> Symbolic link behavior—If the path points to a symbolic link, the
> function creates a hard link to the target.

Now I'm stuck wondering, what's the solution to this? How can I create a hardlink that points to a symbolic link itself as opposed to the target? I did notice Windows' internal command `MKLINK` appears to be able to create hardlinks to symlinks. So theoretically, I guess I could just use the `system` function in C, but to be honest, it feels lazy and I tend to avoid it. Is there possibly a solution using only the Win32 API?

I also came across some code snippets from a Google developer ([[1]](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2015/12/between-rock-and-hard-link.html) [[2]](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/symboliclink-testing-tools/tree/00c0fe4cefcd2a62c887fe6117abc02bc98bb9fb)), with some details on the implementation of `CreateHardLink` and whatnot, but it seemed a little too low level for me to make any real sense out of it. Also, (and I could be wrong about this) the functions provided in the GitHub repo seem to only be compatible with Windows 10 and later, but I'd hope to at least support Windows 7 as well.

Comment: in what problem when you already point by self to ready code ? all what you need that open file with `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` or `FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` options. and than use documented [`FILE_LINK_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_link_information) with [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile)

Comment: however i look - really `CreateHardLink` create hard link to the symbolic links themselves, not the target. documentation is wrong. so you can simply use `CreateHardLink` as is. *Windows' internal command MKLINK appears to be able to create hardlinks to symlinks* - it simply call `CreateHardLink` too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CreateHardLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createhardlinkw) create hard link to the symbolic link (reparse point) themselves, not to the target. so documentation simply is wrong. the `lpExistingFileName` opened with option `FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT`
so you can simply use `CreateHardLink` as is and nothing more need todo. visa versa - if you want create hard link to target, you need custom implementation of `CreateHardLink` and not use `FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` (if you will use `NtOpenFile`) or `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` if you use `CreatFileW` )

> I did notice Windows' internal command MKLINK appears to be able to
> create hardlinks to symlinks.

if you debug *cmd.exe* with `mklink` command you easy can notice that also simply `CreateHardLinkW` api called (set breakpoint to it)

---

after you create hardlink to symlink file you can view in explorer that type of file is *.symlink* . for test we can remove link from target file ( by use `FSCTL_DELETE_REPARSE_POINT`) if hardlink point to target - any operation with symlink not affect hardlink. but if we created hardlink to symlink intself - after break symlink - hard link will also be breaked:

```
void TestCreateHardLink(PCWSTR lpFileName, PCWSTR lpSymlinkFileName, PCWSTR lpExistingFileName)
{
    if (CreateSymbolicLinkW(lpSymlinkFileName, lpExistingFileName, 0))
    {
        if (CreateHardLinkW(lpFileName, lpSymlinkFileName, 0))
        {
            HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(lpSymlinkFileName, FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 
                FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, 0);

            if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER rdb = { IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK };
                OVERLAPPED ov {};
                if (DeviceIoControl(hFile, FSCTL_DELETE_REPARSE_POINT, &rdb, sizeof(rdb), 0, 0, 0, &ov))
                {
                    MessageBoxW(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
                CloseHandle(hFile);
            }
            DeleteFileW(lpFileName);
        }
        DeleteFileW(lpSymlinkFileName);
    }
}
```

we want more flexible implementation of hardlink create (set target) , can use next code:

```
HRESULT CreateHardLinkExW(PCWSTR lpFileName, PCWSTR lpExistingFileName, BOOLEAN ReplaceIfExisting, BOOLEAN bToTarget)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(lpExistingFileName, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING,
        bToTarget ? FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS : FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS|FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, 0);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    UNICODE_STRING NtName;
    NTSTATUS status = RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus(lpFileName, &NtName, 0, 0);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        ULONG Length = FIELD_OFFSET(FILE_LINK_INFORMATION, FileName) + NtName.Length;

        if (PFILE_LINK_INFORMATION LinkInfo = (PFILE_LINK_INFORMATION)_malloca(Length))
        {
            LinkInfo->ReplaceIfExists = ReplaceIfExisting;
            LinkInfo->RootDirectory = 0;
            LinkInfo->FileNameLength = NtName.Length;
            memcpy(LinkInfo->FileName, NtName.Buffer, NtName.Length);
            IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
            status = NtSetInformationFile(hFile, &iosb, LinkInfo, Length, FileLinkInformation);
        }
        else
        {
            status = STATUS_NO_MEMORY;
        }

        RtlFreeUnicodeString(&NtName);
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return 0 > status ? HRESULT_FROM_NT(status) : S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Well, this definitely teaches me not to trust documentation. The weird thing is, even the page for [symbolic links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/symbolic-link-effects-on-file-systems-functions) says it links to the symlink target. Guess it must be a copy-paste... Anyway, to verify that the behavior hasn't changed between OS versions, I tested `CreateHardLinkW` on both Windows 7 and 10, and indeed, it *does* hardlink to the symlink (NOT the target of the symlink, as documented). Thanks!

Comment: @user966939 i look this on xp and even here hard link created on symlink, not on target

Comment: How did you create a symlink on XP? I thought they were not a thing on XP? Wanted to check there too myself.

Comment: @user966939 symlink (reparse point with tag `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK`) on xp create possible but system not understand this tag and link not functional. but task not in this - i say *even here hard link created on symlink, not on target*  and this is true - simply look for `CreateHardLinkW` on xp and easy visible that file (on which we try create hard link) opened with `FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` option. this is mean that hardlink will be directly for this file, not for target